# Null or empty values are not stored in solr

Tags: solr

I have solr database where I inserted string field like this:

```
{
    "add-field": [    
        {
            "name": "string__single_line_text_field__LC",
            "type": "string",
            "stored": true,
            "indexed": true,
            "required": true,
            "default": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I set field to be required and define its default value. In my solr database, this field is like this:

[image]

The problem is because solr doesn't store my default value as empty string when string is null or empty (it simply doesn't exist) - it stores only non null/non empty values. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to add an explicit default value (i.e. not an empty string) to see if that changes anything (i.e. is it an issue with the indexing process or a configuration issue)? What is the reason for having an empty string as the default value? (i.e. for the field to be present, but not have a value?)

Comment: When I add explicit default value, it works... Empty value is needed because client want to search for all object where some field = "". But since field is not there inside the object, they don't get the proper results.

Comment: While I can't say why you don't get the default field from the information you've provided, you can query for documents where a field is missing by using `*:* -field:[* TO *]` - that will give you all the documents where a field isn't present